# @MockBean-instance used via @Autowire before method injection

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5

In my JUNIT5-test I want to mock a bean by @MockBean. In my @BeforeEach - method the calls are injected.
But other beans @Autowire-ing the @MockBean are instantiated with the @MockBean before the method injection. This is weird and gives me NPEs. How can I force method injection before use of the @MockBean?

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:context/authenticationStaff.xml")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class PasswordPolicyServiceTest {

    private final List<Reference> bcryptDigestRefs = new ArrayList<>();
    private final DigestHistoryRule bcryptDigestRule = new DigestHistoryRule(new BCryptHashBean());
    @MockBean
    private SystemConfiguration systemConfiguration; 

    @BeforeEach
    public void initMock() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Arrays.asList(SystemConfigKey.values()).forEach(key -> {
            Mockito.when(systemConfiguration.getConfig(key)).thenReturn(getConfig(key, key.getDefaultValue()));
        });
        Mockito.when(systemConfiguration.getConfig(SystemConfigKey.MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH)).thenReturn(getConfig(SystemConfigKey.MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH, "5"));
```

A failing class is:

```
@Service
public class SessionCacheManager {


    private final Ehcache ehCache;

    private final Cache<String, SessionVerificationType> sessionCache;

    private final SystemConfiguration systemConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    public SessionCacheManager(final Ehcache ehCache, final SystemConfiguration systemConfiguration) {
        this.ehCache=ehCache;
        this.systemConfiguration=systemConfiguration;
        SystemConfigType systemConfig = systemConfiguration.getConfig(SystemConfigKey.SESSION_MAX_NUMBER);
        Integer numberOfParalledSessions = systemConfig.getIntegerValue();
        CacheManager cacheManager=ehCache.registerNewCacheManager(CACHE_MANAGER);
        sessionCache = cacheManager.createCache(CACHE_NAME, 
                CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(String.class, SessionVerificationType.class, ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(numberOfParalledSessions)));
    }
```

As I can see (with debug), the "SessionCacheManager" uses the mocked "SystemConfiguration" but systemConfiguration.getConfig(SystemConfigKey.SESSION_MAX_NUMBER); returns a null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped myself, though I do not like my solution. It is more a trick than a solution. But I cannot think of something else right now.

I change the @ContextConfiguration to:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/context/authenticationStaff.xml", classes = { SpringApplicationContext.class })
```

The XML is setup, that it cannot autodetect the class "SystemConfiguration.class".
Instead of that the "SpringApplicationContext.class" provides the "SystemConfiguration.class" as a mocked bean.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringApplicationContext {

    @Mock
    private SystemConfiguration mockedSystemConfiguration;

    @Bean
    public SystemConfiguration systemConfiguration() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Arrays.asList(SystemConfigKey.values()).forEach(key -> {
            Mockito.when(mockedSystemConfiguration.getConfig(key)).thenReturn(getConfig(key, key.getDefaultValue()));
        });
        Mockito.when(mockedSystemConfiguration.getConfig(SystemConfigKey.MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH)).thenReturn(getConfig(SystemConfigKey.MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH, "5"));
        Mockito.when(mockedSystemConfiguration.getConfig(SystemConfigKey.PASSWORD_BCRYPTENCODER_COSTFACTOR)).thenReturn(getConfig(SystemConfigKey.PASSWORD_BCRYPTENCODER_COSTFACTOR, "5"));
        return mockedSystemConfiguration;
    }

    private SystemConfigType getConfig(SystemConfigKey key, String value) {
        SystemConfigType config = new SystemConfigType();
        config.setKey(key);
        config.setValue(value); 
        return config;
    }
```

The test-code now looks like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/context/authenticationStaff.xml", classes = { SpringApplicationContext.class })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class PasswordPolicyServiceTest {

    @Autowired 
    private PasswordPolicyService passwordPolicyService;
    @Autowired 
    private PasswordHandlerService passwordHandlerService;
    @Autowired
    private SystemConfiguration systemConfiguration;

    private final List<Reference> bcryptDigestRefs = new ArrayList<>();

    private final DigestHistoryRule bcryptDigestRule = new DigestHistoryRule(new BCryptHashBean());

    @BeforeEach
    public void initMock() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        String password=passwordHandlerService.getPassword("my$Password");
        bcryptDigestRefs.add(
                new HistoricalReference(
                        "bcrypt-history",
                        password));
    }
```

This works, but is not a nice solution. Other recommendations are very welcome.